# What version of typedef should I use for node@16 with ts4.8?

Tags: node.js, typescript

We use nodejs v16 and typescript v4.8.

As I can see there is no such type definition support both of them:

[image: dist-tags @types/node]

So what version should I choose? Can I use latest @types/node@20 for nodejs@16 ?

Comment: If latest works you should use latest.